# Run jquery inside ajax when loading only a section and not an entire page?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$("#option1").live("click", function(){
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#main").load("option1.php", function(){
    });
});
```

and the script inside runs perfectly.  However what I really need is to call only one section of the option1.php page, like this:

```
$("#option1").live("click", function(){
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#main").load("option1.php #container", function(){
    });
});
```

Bute then the script stops working, I'm assuming that is because I'm leaving out the head tags that contain the script.  How can I make it run while loading only one section of the page? is it possible?

Comment: i think you are referring to this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I understand that you have on the server a html page (or server generated in PHP) , that contains several sections, and you would want your Ajax call to only retrieve that specific part from the page. Is that so ?

Comment: @ Herr Kaleun, thank you, your suggestion was spot on :).  @tsimbalar, that's exactly what I was looking for, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a PHP script, you can easily send only a part of your page.
After, to load that, you can use the `$.ajax` jquery object :

```
function loadContainer()
{
    var ajaxobject = $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"option1.php",
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        global:false,
        dataType:"html",
        data:"part=container",
        timeout:10000,
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#container').html(data);
        },
        error:function()
        {
            alert('Error; Unable to load option1.php');
        }
    });
    if(ajaxobject == undefined)
        alert('Ajax object creation failed');
}
```

On the PHP side, you just need to check if `$_POST['part']` equals `container`.
If yes, send only the part you want to send.

Comment: Thanks cfillion, I'm not sure if I can use this because basically the #container section is php-free, only html.  Or maybe this is too advanced for me and I don't quite understand :)

Comment: To use my code, just call the `loadContainer()` function. My script will just load `option1.php` and write its content into the `#container` element. See that for more exemples : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand better now.  I made it work using Herr Kaleun's suggestion first but will try your option to learn something new :)